# Prove that any real random variable takes only countable number of values with positive probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Equivalently, is it possible for uncountable number of positives to sum to $1$?

I was thinking about bounding some how the numbers to prove that it is not possible (I have a feeling that it is not possible, I haven't encountered a random variable that takes uncountably many values with positive probability).
Now suppose that there exists a random variable $X$ that takes all values in $[0,1]$ with positive probability (because any uncountable set can be mapped to $[0,1]$). Now, pick the maximum of the probabilities, then pick second maximum and so on and sum them. If that is more than $1$ we get a contradiction. But there are many problems with this greedy approach:

1. We are going along a sequence, that can be summed to $1$, even if all the probabilities can't be.
2. Uncountable sets are not enumerable by definition.

How do I go about proving it?

Comment: It does, thank you @ClementYung.